# CALCULATING DIFFERENCE between percentages derived from two different numbers (help)

Tags: prediction, descriptive-statistics, difference-in-difference, percentage

I recently came across a graph comparing education levels between foreign born immigrants and US born citizens that was divided into four categories. 
Less than highschool,
Highschool graduate,
Some college,
Bachelor or more

9% of us born did not graduate
And
27% of foreign born did not graduate

The graph further breaks down into 7 birth places the immigrants came from and their individual education alone.
Since I have already did the math I will use this as an example

Mexico born 54% didn’t graduate

Someone told me I did not know how to read a map as they are an engineer and work with statistics everyday. Because I read the map as if there were just as many foreign born immigrants as there were US born the percentages would be different.

US BORN 9%,

MEXICO BORN 54%

If you look at the chart you would say there is a 45% difference in how many Mexicans graduate versus Americans. 
I say that is false. Since the number they calculated the percentages from are not the same.

Say there is 
300,000,000 US BORN

and

300,000 Mexican born

There is no way to calculate the percent of how many Mexicans would not graduate if there were 300,000,000. If there is I couldn’t find it.

I ended up finding the percent difference which ended up being 5%

Does that mean there is only a 5% difference in how many US-MEXICO BORN graduate? 
If so, could you calculate the number of mexico born who wouldn’t graduate if they were the same as US BORN?

Is there any other way to come to a more accurate conclusion of the difference in the two?

How does someone else read this kind of graph?

To say 54 percent of Mexicans didn’t finish high school is insinuating that the more that come over will keep the results the same? 
I don’t see how

Also I found the percent difference by 
Finding the 9% of US born 
.09x300,000,000=27,000,000

The Mexico born
.57x300,000=171,000

27,000,000-171,000=269,829,000

27,000,000+171,000=27,171,000

27,171,000/2=13,585,500

13,585,500/269,829,000=.05

5%

I don’t know if the percent difference is accurate because again the percentages weren’t derived from the same number. 
Also if it is correct, does that imply the difference between how many did not graduate is alone 5%. Stating there isn’t much of a difference between how many do not graduate?

If you were to say welfare is used primarily by those who do not graduate, I’m trying to prove that you cannot say more immigrants = more welfare. Especially if the same amount do graduate and pay into taxes, would it not cancel itself out. Not costing Americans anymore money?

My whole view was if their are less foreign born population than US born than the more there were the percentages would change, possibly with even less percentage not graduating.[image]

Comment: I'm trying to follow your question but it is not entirely clear to me what you are asking. Do you happen to have a picture of the graph in question? Can you please try to explain what exactly is the data and what you are trying to determine?

Comment: I added the picture of the graph. I’m asking how can you compare the amount of immigrants who don’t graduate to the amount of Americans who don’t graduate. 

The assumption was we don’t need anymore immigrants becoming citizens because of the amount who already don’t complete high school. Not completing high school makes them more prone to using welfare. 

My assumption was since the population was less for immigrants it affected the overall percentages. If there were more the percentages would change. 

I don’t think you can predict whether the percentages would increase or decrease?

Comment: If we allowed more to become citizens. 

So I tried to compare the percentages based on the actual number each percentage was derived from to see the real difference between the two. If the percentages would be affected by total number. Then probability wise wouldn’t it negatively affect the percentages if the total number was less? If there were more in total number wouldn’t it give more of an opportunity for the percentages to increase in a positive manor? If you take the ratios then the number has to be affected? Right?

Comment: So the judgement that because so many already don’t graduate allowing more would mean more wouldn’t graduate, I can’t find the logical explanation to this ?

Comment: Thanks for adding these details. I'm doing my best to follow your argument. As far as I can tell, you can't really compare the two groups except on a percentage basis. Once you change the assumptions (e.g. more people immigrating, etc.) you cannot assume that the same patterns would hold. You are also assuming that not graduating = more welfare, which is not necessarily the case. The graph doesn't actually state whether the foreign-born immigrants are or are not citizens. It's possible that some of the foreign-born immigrants were naturalized and others were not.

Comment: That also means that you can't make assumptions about whether or not naturalizing them would make a difference. It is possible, for example, that the educational attainment is different for immigrants who are naturalized vs. those who are not. Sorry if this isn't exactly what you were hoping to find out, but I don't see a way you can easily compare them. All this graph tells you is an estimate of what % of each category has a certain educational attainment. BTW: Pew Surveys are statistically calibrated, but they are not actually measuring it for each of the 300M or however many Americans.